# Swift Custom UIViewController's label is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I customized a viewcontroller with xib, and this viewcontroller has a label.

I have already connected the label with xib.

But when I use this label, it is nil.

What's wrong I did?

below is my code.

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

code to use this viewcontroller

```
    let myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
    myViewController.label.text = "test"
    presentViewController(myViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        println("ok")
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  issue is you are trying to access the label before it is loaded.

The following changes may solve your problem;

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var labelText: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Setting Label text here
        label.text = labelText;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

and

```
let myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
    myViewController.labelText = "test"
    presentViewController(myViewController, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        println("ok")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. And i try your code, but label in viewDidLoad is still nil. And i try viewDidAppear is nil too

Comment: Check your IBoutlet if it is connected properly.

Comment: You are right. It's IBoutlet problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Did not work for me in Xcode 7.3. The difference is that I did not use nib file but designed it in IB. Any idea on how to overcome the problem

Comment: Ignore my comment above. I found out my problem. It was that my label outlet was invalid - probably during the design I deleted the label in the storyBoard and did not recreated a new outlet, so the old outlet stayed in the code but was invalid. Once I deleted the outlet and created a new one the problem was gone. Would have been nice if when deleting an object in the storyBoard the corresponding outlet will be deleted also, or marked somehow as invalid, and not simply as nil

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:):

> The nib file you specify is not loaded right away. It is loaded the first time the view controller's view is accessed. If you want to perform additional initialization after the nib file is loaded, override the viewDidLoad method and perform your tasks there.

You may access the label from `viewDidLoad`. If you need to access the label externally, make sure you have accessed the `view` property first to force the view to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The view of the view controller is not loaded. You can either use the viewDidLoad() method inside your view controller or you load it by accessing the view property. It is lazy loaded and will load your view.
So before accessing viewController.view.label write print(viewController.view) to lazy load the view